# Difference between an IIFE and non-IIFE in JavaScript Modular approach

Tags: javascript, module, iife

Recently while I was trying  to learn  more about IIFE and modules in JavaScript
a question came to my mind that how is IIFE making a Module while not Immediately
Invoking the function doesn't make it a module..

can anyone  share with me the Difference between this code

```
var MODULE = (function () {
var my = {},
    privateVariable = 1;

function privateMethod() {
    // ...
}

my.moduleProperty = 1;
my.moduleMethod = function () {
    // ...
};

return my;
}());
```

and this code where the function is not Immediately Invoked..

```
var MODULE = function () {
var my = {},
    privateVariable = 1;

function privateMethod() {
    // ...
}

my.moduleProperty = 1;
my.moduleMethod = function () {
    // ...
};

return my;
};
```

Does the second block of code means that Module is just a function that itself returns an object?

IF I use the second variable like this

```
var ModuleObj = Module();
```

Will this work the same as the first Code block that I shared like IIFE.. Kind of confused...

Answer (score 9):

Yeah you pretty much got the idea of the difference between the two, let's look at why you might want one over the other.

An IIFE is useful to isolate the scope. It lets you keep the variables you define private inside the IIFE without polluting the global space around it. It's a nice way to compose a function that has some variables you don't need lurking around. Let's minimize this example a bit.

```
var Counter = (function () {
  var count = 0;

  var counter = {
    add: function () {
      count++;
    },
    subtract: function () {
      count--;
    },
    getCount: function () {
      return count;
    }
  }
  return counter;
})();

Counter.add();
Counter.add();
Counter.getCount(); // 2
Counter.subtract();
Counter.getCount(); // 1
```

What happens above is that we're able to compose this "counter" functionality without leaking the private information, like `count`. It'd be bad if other things could override it by accident. Also what happens is that right away we can assign `Counter` to the *result* of the IFFE -- the `counter` set of functions. `Counter` is now equal to that, and `counter` is able to retain access to `count` since it was defined in the same scope.

The benefit here is that we're able to assign a variable to this composition of functionality. The IIFE basically allows us to **immediately return** what we `return` inside of it. Since we assign `Counter` to the IIFE, and the IIFE returns the functionality inside of it, `Counter` is now a fully functional component.

We don't always have to use IIFE. It's really handy when you want to "tuck away" the implementation details and return an API.

---

So, what if we had the same thing, but it wasn't an IIFE -- just a function?

Just like your example, we'd have to call it in order to get the "instance".

```
var CounterFactory = function () {
  var count = 0;
  var counter = {
    add: //...
    subtract: //...
    getCount: //...
  };
  return counter;
};

var CounterA = CounterFactory();
var CounterB = CounterFactory();

CounterA.add();
CounterA.add();
CounterA.getCount(); // 2

CounterB.add();
CounterB.getCount(); // 1
```

See the difference? It's all about what the function is returning. In the first example we only get a single `Counter` instance, which may be perfectly fine. In the second example, it's more of a "factory" -- it generates an *instance* of `counter` and we can call that multiple times and get multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok an IIFE runs the functions within it and defines the variable MODULE to the return of that function. The other declares the MODULE variable to the function itself.

Think of it this way (also try it in your console to see the results).

### This code does not run the console.log method.

```
(function(){
    console.log('ran')
});
```

### This code does

```
(function(){
    console.log('ran')
})();
```

So the whole point of the IIFE is to run the function before doing anything and the (); at the end does this.

If we take the code that did not run and assign it to a value what happens?

```
var foo = (function(){
    console.log('ran')
});
foo();
```

We have a function foo that we can execute.

So what is the point of an IIFE if we can just assign it and run it later? The answer to that is local variables which you can use for closure later.

```
console.log(num); //get undefined
(function(){
    var num = 'ran';
    console.log(num) //get 'ran'
})();
console.log(num); //get undefined
```

We get undefined ran then undefined so the values we declare in the function stay in the function and nothing else can get to them. This is the lexical scoping that JavaScript runs off of.

Just for fun lets do a closure with it.

```
var add = (function(){
    var num = 0;
    return function(){
        console.log(num++);
    }
})();
console.log(num) //get undefined
add() //get 1
add() //get 2
console.log(num) //still undefined
```